# In connected webpart (using sharepoint 2007) ,option button should be selected by default

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a web part connected to another (provide a row to). It shows the radio button that when clicked correctly provides the data to the second web part.

Can I have this radio button selected by default so that it automatically provides the filter data as soon as the page is loaded?

if you find any jquery/javascript relevent to this please share it and will be more helpful to me.

Comment: $('#radioId').attr('checked','checked') in onload would do simply the checking, but i assume you want to fire the webpart connection event as well? I think if it's a custom webpart you could also do this in code behind as well.

Comment: since i am newbie,please share some more information regarding this.

Comment: is the webpart programmed by you or your company or is it a standard or thirdparty wepbart you use?

Answer (score 1):

When you click the radio button from jQuery, the event should be raised as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("input:radio[value='your-value-goes-here']").click();

});
```

Be cautious if you use the value more than once on the page! If possible address the radio button with an id:

```
$("#Your-Radio-Button-Id").click();
```